# Eagle cad dimension measurement showing on top and bottom layer when creating Gerber files

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, routing, gerber

[image: Eagle router view (left) and top layer only view after Gerber generation]

I have an Eagle design as shown in the 1st image attached. The dimension measurements are on "dimensions" layer 20. When I create Gerber files then look at it in a viewer, I get the measurement arrows etched right on the board. It goes across the ground planes. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Check your CAM generation for which layers are included in the gerber files. Though that does not appear to be the same dimension arrow you may have some hidden layers adding to (or subtracting from) the gerber.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Samuel. I tried this many times. I mad sure only the top layer was selected when generating the Gerber file. What you see in the right image was generated from .GTL file with only layer 1. I cropped the images but it is the dimension arrows that are bieng etched on the pcb. I'm so puzzled..

Comment: And deleting the dimension arrows makes it go away? You aren't showing us the same images though, you haven't flooded the copper pour in the first image.

Answer (score 2):

The "dimension" layer in Eagle is unfortunately named.  Other CAD/CAM programs might refer to this as a "routing layer".  It is intended to show the outer dimensions of the PCB. It basically shows where the PCB should be cut by a drill or router.

Some of the items in this layer must be placed manually. For example, you should draw your board outline on this layer.

Other features are added automatically. E.g. if you place a 125-mil non-plated drill hit on the board, there will be a 125-mil circle placed on the dimension layer.

One of the design rules sets the clearance distance from any feature on a copper layer to anything on the dimension layer.  This is very convenient with copper pours.  If you choose a 20-mil dimension clearance, the copper is "pulled back" 20-mils away from any cut edges of the board.  This prevents copper from being exposed on the edges of a multi-layer PCB, either on the outer periphery or on the inner edges of drill holes.

So now you see: When you drew lines on the dimension layer, Eagle "conveniently" removed copper from around those lines :)

Comment: Indeed. Rather than the "dimension" layer, measurements should go on the "measures" layer.